# Design the UI for a card game in html and css

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

[image: classic solitaire]

I am trying to create the classic solitaire game in Javascript, but I am uncertain about how to design the HTML/CSS part of the game.

Requirements:

1. Animation. Dealing cards, shuffling cards etc. should be animated.
2. Each card can be dragged and dropped.

Here is my question:

What are the general strategies/techniques to position the elements in HTML5 games? Apparently in this game, we may not want to simply hard-code a card's position to something like `top: 30px; left: 50px` etc, because it has to adopt itself to different screen sizes, not to mention it has to align with other cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends mostly on how you want to go about it, but I would recommend using `<canvas>`. It supports animations, click handlers, everything you would need.

Also, there's the absolutely **beautiful** library **[CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/)** that you can take advantage of, which handles things like bitmaps, tweens, sounds, pre-loading large images, you name it!

If you'd prefer to just use a regular canvas, **plenty** of tutorials like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VNtfAGt5no) that work specifically with card games in canvas.

As for clicking and dragging, the general concept is that you calculate where the object is by calculating the offset from the edge of the canvas. CreateJS allows you to easily have an 'object' that sits on the canvas, so it will automatically come complete with its own width and height. You can both define the offset and move it around with standard object syntax, using something along the lines of:

```
card.x = game_board.x + 100;
```

Having said that, there's no need to re-invent the wheel! [Simon Sarris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154112/simon-sarris) has created a great tutorial on clicking and dragging objects in canvas, which can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161220195326/http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful).

Hope this helps! :)